# Unable to install g++ compiler in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, g++

First I updated like this `sudo apt-get update`
last it shows like below:

```
Fetched 323 kB in 1s (247 kB/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then I install g++ compiler. It shows like below:

```
bharat@bharat-OptiPlex-3050:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  canonical-poke libappindicator1 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgnome-2-0
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common liborbit-2-0
  linux-headers-4.4.0-23 linux-headers-4.4.0-23-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-23-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I need solution for this please help me.

Comment: The messages say g++ is already installed, and already the latest [default] version (for 16.04; https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=g%2B%2B).  If you want more, please clarify what you want

Answer (score 0):

> g++ is already the newest version

It seems You already Installed the latest version

Try:

> sudo apt autoremove
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade